# How to add double quotes to sequence of char inside a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string in Python like that one:

```
'speed=36.2448,course=331.35,gps_time=2021-11-22T00:43:22.678Z,fix=1,message_source=device_gps,period_km=0.436,location=Middle of no where,x=3.2'
```

and I need to add double quotes to non-numerical string situated between a `'='` and a `','`. Result should looks like this:

```
'speed=36.2448,course=331.35,gps_time="2021-11-22T00:43:22.678Z",fix=1,message_source="device_gps",period_km=0.436,location="Middle of no where",x=3.2'
```

I'm trying with regex since hours but turning crazy.
Any help would be welcome. In advance thank you.

Comment: Are you sure commas are separators? IIRC you can escape commas in the line protocol with a backslash to make them literal commas. Do you want to handle this case or will this not be a problem? What regex have you tried, and what went wrong with it?

Comment: How general are you trying to be? Is it always going to be the same name=value pairs separated by commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a pattern with a capture group, and in the replacement use the capture group between double quotes.

```
=(?!\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,|$))([^",\n]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vHJk6P/1)

The pattern matches:

- `=` Match literally
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,|$)` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part followed by either `,` or end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^",\n]+` match 1+ times any character except `"` `,` or a newline
- `)` Close group 1

For example

```
import re

regex = r"=(?!\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,|$))([^\",\n]+)"
s = 'speed=36.2448,course=331.35,gps_time=2021-11-22T00:43:22.678Z,fix=1,message_source=device_gps,period_km=0.436,location=Middle of no where,x=3.2'
result = re.sub(regex, r'="\1"', s)
print(result)
```

Output

```
speed=36.2448,course=331.35,gps_time="2021-11-22T00:43:22.678Z",fix=1,message_source="device_gps",period_km=0.436,location="Middle of no where",x=3.2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about handling escaped commas, you can simply split the string on commas, then split on `=`, handle the right side based on if it's numeric or not, and finally join everything.

```
s = 'speed=36.2448,course=331.35,gps_time=2021-11-22T00:43:22.678Z,fix=1,message_source=device_gps,period_km=0.436,location=Middle of no where,x=3.2'

items = []
for item in s.split(','):
    lhs, rhs = item.split('=', 1)
    try:
        float(rhs)
        # Could convert rhs to float, so leave item unchanged
        items.append(item)
    except ValueError:
        # Could not convert rhs to float, so is not numeric. Surround rhs with quotes
        items.append(f'{lhs}="{rhs}"')

modified_s = ",".join(items)
```

which gives

```
modified_s = 'speed=36.2448,course=331.35,gps_time="2021-11-22T00:43:22.678Z",fix=1,message_source="device_gps",period_km=0.436,location="Middle of no where",x=3.2'
```